# AngularJS Hide rows from table on given condition when a button is clicked

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to hide some rows from a table when a button is clicked. I want to hide just the rows where the number of exams is equals to zero.

**HTML code:**

```
    <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <button ng-click="hide();"> HIDE ROWS</button>
        <br/>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Exams</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-class="{'showNot' : item.examsNum === 0}" ng-repeat="item in data.records">
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.examsNum}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

AngularJS:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        records: [{
            name: 'Mel',
            examsNum: 2
        }, {
            name: 'Sarah',
            examsNum: 2
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            examsNum: 0
        }]
    }; 

    $scope.hide = function () { 
        angular.element('.showNot').css("display", "none");
    };
}]);
```

Here is the jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/meldromer/239bqa2g/7/)

I'm pretty new to AngularJS, and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a show/hide flag, and use it in ng-show along with the zero check:
[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1a05z1jx/).

```
        <div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-click="hide();"> HIDE ROWS</button>
    <br/>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Exams</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-hide="(item.examsNum == 0) && hideZero" ng-repeat="item in data.records">
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.examsNum}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and

```
    myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        records: [{
            name: 'Mel',
            examsNum: 2
        }, {
            name: 'Sarah',
            examsNum: 2
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            examsNum: 0
        }]
    }; 

    $scope.hide = function () { 
        $scope.hideZero = !$scope.hideZero;
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give an id to your table `<table id="table">` then change your selector to

```
var elem = document.querySelector('#table');
angular.element(elem.querySelector('.showNot')).css('display', 'none')
```

We cant use class selectors easily in jQlite - `Limited to lookups by tag name` but this should work your you

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/239bqa2g/9/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the ng-show or ng-hide directive insted of display none

html

```
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <button ng-click="hide()"> HIDE ROWS</button>
        <br/>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Exams</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-show="Display" ng-repeat="item in data.records">
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.examsNum}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
 </div>
```

script

```
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        records: [{
            name: 'Mel',
            examsNum: 2
        }, {
            name: 'Sarah',
            examsNum: 2
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            examsNum: 0
        }]
    }; 

    $scope.Display = true;

    $scope.hide = function () { 
       $scope.Display = !$scope.Display ;
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a filter is more correct.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter

Filters may be used to hide items in a list based on some criteria - which sounds like what you are doing

Answer (score -1):

Okay. So you got something wrong over here. the 'item' is only available inside the scope of ng-repeat. You cannot access it at the same level as ng-repeat. 
[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rfrd4jAWq0xOrBFNPmIU?p=preview) is a working version of your code. And please use ng-hide/ng-show for such things. Its more efficient.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="myController">
        <button ng-click="hide();"> HIDE ROWS</button>
        <br />

        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Exams</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in data.records">

              <td ng-hide='item.examsNum === 0'>{{item.name}}</td>
              <td ng-hide='item.examsNum === 0'>{{item.examsNum}}</td>

            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Someone just downvoted me? I don't understand why? The plunkr works just fine. And I did correct the problem using pure angular and no jquery. Hoping to get some explanation regarding this from whoever downvoted me.

Comment: The problem with this is that the rows with item.examsNum === 0 are hidden by default, they should hide when the button is pressed.